# VSCode latex-workshop command not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex

I just cannot find any actions to work of the latex-workshop extension in VS Code, though it worked well yesterday.

When I tried to find the actions (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>), it shows a choice of `LaTex Workshop: All Actions`. However, after click on it, an error occurs as `command 'latex-workshop.actions' not found`, and nothing happens. And I can't use any command by shortcut keys.

I tried to reload and reinstall the extension, but they don't help.

Does anyone know what's happening here?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, and followed some suggestion in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/626).
Simply reinstalling the plugin won't work, but I fixed like this:

1. Uninstall extension
2. Close VS Code (Make sure all processes are shut down, maybe restart your machine)
3. Open Code and reinstall the extension

Comment: This may also help: https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/1213#issuecomment-470116095

Answer (score 2):

For me, what solved the problem (August 2021) was to revert to an earlier version - the problem was in 8.20.2, I reverted to 8.19.2. Just click on the extension to show its menu screen and hit the drop-down arrow of the "Uninstall" button.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by uninstalling the extension and deleting the folder

`/.vscode-oss/extensions/james-yu.latex-workshop-8.14.0/`

The name may vary across distributions

Comment: This worked perfectly for me on 11 June 2021. I also quit out of VS Code before deleting the folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
[neither build, view or buid on ctrl+s worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwQAG.png)

It appears that I had a code instance of a latex project open when I moved folders around on my machine.
It was still open when the folder didn´t exist anymore, which also broke other code instances ( or rather the extension in them )

I did not have to reinstall the extension or reboot the machine.
Simply closing all VScode instances was sufficient.
The extension is working as intended again.